# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker, commonjs

При подключении JavaScript компонента Date Range Picker (http://www.daterangepicker.com) консоль выводит ошибку, указанную в заголовке.

Подключаю плагин в main.js следующим образом:

```js
window.$ = require('jquery');
window.moment = require('moment');

require('daterangepicker/daterangepicker');

$('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker(); // строка выдает ошибку в консоль
```

Сборку произвожу с помощью Gulp и Browserify.

Comment: Может глупый вопрос, но всё-же... А `input` у вас такой есть? Покажите свою вёрстку.

Comment: Сам файл, где-то установлен командой `bower ..` или через `npm ...` или просто подключен? По вашей ошибке он просто не подгружен, в документ, который его вызывает.

Comment: HTML: `<input name="dates" />` package.json: `{ ... "dependencies": { "bootstrap": "^4.1.1", "daterangepicker": "^3.0.3", "jquery": "^3.3.1", "moment": "^2.22.2", "moment-parseformat": "^3.0.0", ... } }` "По вашей ошибке он просто не подгружен, в документ, который его вызывает" - в том и дело, что он подгружается, и в собранном файле данный компонент присутствует, но такое впечатление, что этот компонент почему-то не отрабатывает.

Comment: `var daterangepicker = require('daterangepicker/daterangepicker');` - так попробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось таким:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```